# How to stop Thread in service when its in offline?

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I am working on an android app with calling webservice when it has internet  by using service and broadcast receivers below is my code:

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {
private static String TAG = YourService.class.getSimpleName();
private MyThread mythread;
public boolean isRunning = false;
JSONArray SaveOrderDart,SaveOrderDetails,UpdateDart,updateOrderDetails;
private static String urlDartorder= Config.url+"SaveDartDetails";
private static String urlupdateOrderDetails= Config.url+"UpdateOrderDetails";
private static String urlSaveOrderDetails= Config.url+"SaveOrderDetails";
private static String urlDartupdate= Config.url+"UpdateDartDetails";
DartDatabase ddb;
OrderDatabase ord;

/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
public YourService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mythread=new MyThread();
}

public YourService()
{
    super("call webservice");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    boolean isNetworkConnected = extras.getBoolean("isNetworkConnected");
    // your code
    if(isNetworkConnected){
        if(!isRunning){
            mythread.start();

            isRunning = true;
        }
        Log.e("TAG", "Yes");


    }
    else {

        if (mythread != null) {

            isRunning = false;
            mythread.interrupt();


        }
        //mythread.stop();
    }


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(!isRunning){
        mythread.start();

        isRunning = true;
    }
}
```

My broadcastreceiver

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

boolean mLastState =false;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that which service class will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            YourService.class.getName());

            //mLastState = true;
            intent.putExtra("isNetworkConnected", isConnected(context));
            context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));


}

public  boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}

}
```

my purpose is when internet is present i want to call webservice not present then stop the thread and service but by this code i can't stop the service i don't no why please help me!
but i can't stop thread please help me!

Comment: There is no need to create a new thread inside onHandleIntent of an IntentSevice class. IntentService itself provides a separate thread which is used to do long running operation. By using IntentService, there is no need for app developer to "manage"  thread. So stopping thread "by hand"  or via code (which is what you are asking) is not required. Read IntentService documentation in Android developer site on how to make use of IntentService for more details.

Comment: iam not getting want you want to say